# Unable to authenticate laravel private channel using Laravel echo server, redis and socket.io

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel Echo server, redis and socket.io for Chat Messages.

I am broadcasting event using.

```
event(new MessageSent($messageThread));
```

This is private channel with method `brodcastOn` as follows:

```
   public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('message.' . $this->broadcastUser->id);
    }
```

My `routes/channels.php` looks like:

```
Broadcast::channel('message.*', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Below is my `laravel-echo-server.json`:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "******",
            "key": "*************"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port":"6379",
            "host":"127.0.0.1",
            "db":"0",
            "password":"****"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    }
```

jQuery for listening to events:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    client: socketio,
    auth: {headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
        }},
});

var userId = window.APP.user;

const channel = window.Echo.channel(`app_database_private-message.${userId}`);

channel.listen('MessageSent', (payload) => {
   console.log('payload', payload)
});
```

this my redis section from `config/database.php`:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
            'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_',
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],
```

It is showing below error:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.0

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

[1:21:22 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost:8000
[1:21:22 PM] - Sending auth request to: http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth

⚠ [1:21:22 PM] - IQ7eT9P_RzF62lRSAAAA could not be authenticated to app_database_private-message.3
        { "message": "", "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException", "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php", "line": 81, "trace": [ { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php", "line": 58, "function": "verifyUserCanAccessChannel", "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\Broadcaster", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php", "line": 319, "function": "auth", "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\RedisBroadcaster", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php", "line": 237, "function": "__call", "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastController.php", "line": 23, "function": "__callStatic", "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade", "type": "::" }, { "function": "authenticate", "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastController", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php", "line": 54, "function": "call_user_func_array" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php", "line": 45, "function": "callAction", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php", "line": 219, "function": "dispatch", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php", "line": 176, "function": "runController", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", "line": 680, "function": "run", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php", "line": 30, "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/app/Http/Middleware/AppMiddleware.php", "line": 55, "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "line": 163, "function": "handle", "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\AppMiddleware", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php", "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php", "line": 41, "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "line": 163, "function": "handle", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php", "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php", "line": 75, "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "line": 163, "function": "handle", "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php", "line": 53, "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/opt/edugem/apps/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php", "line": 49, "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

- On Echo side, you should use

```js
window.Echo.private(`message.${userId}`);
```

You also must ensure that the Laravel config variable `database.redis.options.prefix` is set to `''`.

- On Laravel side, you need to implement a channel's authorization in order to allow a socket to listen to this private channel.

```php
Broadcast::channel('message.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    //Your authorization logic which should return a boolean
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks

Comment: I am already using `Broadcase::channel('message.{userId}'...` in channels.php file. I have updated my question. But still it is not working.

Comment: You need to specify `{id}` instead of `*` in your authorization channel in order to retrieve it from the callback.

Comment: I have done that. Now it is not throwing that error. but it is not logging payload using `console.log(payload)`.

Comment: Show your `redis` section from your `config/database.php` file please

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to set the `prefix` to `''` and it should work

Comment: Thanks. I have update prefix to `''` but still it is showing 
`Channel: app_database_private-message.4` in echo server log. Also, i have run command `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: You need to restart your Laravel worker to refresh its config https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```js
channel.listen('MessageSent', (payload) => {
   console.log('payload', payload)
});
```

use this statement

```js
channel.listen('.MessageSent', (payload) => {
   console.log('payload', payload)
});
```

use dot(.) before namespace in Echo

example

```js
window.Echo(...)
.listen('.namespace')
```

and reWrite `broadcastAs` in Notification Class and use `shouldBroadCastNow`:

```js
broadcastAs(){
return 'namespace'
}
```